# open source code review tool for Informatica Power Center 10.x hosted on Linux

Tags: informatica-powercenter

Do we have any UNIX/Linux based, open source code review tool for Informatica Power Center 10.x ? if so , please share relevant details like download link installation guide etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I'm using:
https://xmlanalyzer.maciejg.pl
Not an open source, but a free one - at least for now :)

Give it a try and let me know if you'd have any questions.